# Which is the cheapest way to get to Vietnam from Europe in summer?

Tags: air-travel, budget, europe, vietnam

The complete question is: Which is the cheapest way to get to Vietnam in summer by flying from Europe? I'm planning a one-month trip to Vietnam for this summer, but I cannot find any reference on what airlines fly from anywhere in Europe to anywhere in Vietnam with or without stops.

In a forum (sorry I've lost the link) somebody told the cheapest is to fly to Bangkok and then fly with Air Asia to Vietnam. Is that the cheapest way? In this case, which is the cheapest route to BKK from Europe?

EDIT: As requested, my country is Spain, but my experience is that Ryanair could take you anywhere in Europe for just 30-60 €, while taking off from Madrid is about 100-300 € more expensive than the same in other european cities. The idea is stay about 4-5 weeks from the first week of july to mid september, but it is also "negotiable" (I have a very flexible work).

Comment: providing your departure country might be helpful.

Comment: europe is big. Getting to CDG, FRA or LHR can also be costly

Comment: Summer is also quite a long time period, could you specify a month?

Comment: Just a reminder: AirAsia is using DMK instead of BKK airport

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For such broad flight searches, a matrix flight search engine is the optimal solution. You could use for example [Google's Matrix Airfare Search](http://matrix.itasoftware.com).

I did a simple search for you:

[image]

For that search query I used Berlin, Germany and all surrounding airports within 1000 miles as origin and all major airports in Vietnam as destination. The screenshots shows the cheapest flight for all the days between 1. of July and 1. of August. As you can see, the cheapest flight is available for 386€.

When we check the details for this flight we see the following:

[image]

Mysteriously, the flight is now only 361€. As you can see the flight departures from Prague and flies to Ho Chi Minh City via Frankfurt. The involved Airlines are Czech Airlines and Vietnam Airlines.

The cheapest non-stop flight from Europe to Vietnam I could find is available for 572€:

[image]

It is a non-stop flight from Paris to Ho Chi Minh City with Vietnam Airlines:

[image]

So generally, I would recommend that you use such flight search engines to find the cheapest and most convenient route for you.

Comment: Cool tool - hadn't seen it! +1 for you

Answer (score 4):

Viet Nam is mostly accessible via hanoi or Ho Chi Minh City (Saigon).

I know that since France has historical relationships with Viet Nam, there are direct flights from Paris to Hanoi on Vietnam Airlines. They are expensive though. I know there are also flights with Qatar Airways, through Doha. They are getting expensive early though, so you should book early. With a few searches, I found flights through Bangkok, as you suggested. Using Skyscanner, I found that the Cathay has flights to Hanoi (through Hong Kong), for not too much.

Comment: Thanks, that is the kind of information I was looking for! I will start looking from these countries using the @RoflcoptrException tool

Comment: @Vince: Now you can fly to Da nang international airport. So check Vietnam airlines