# Airline pricing website with multiple destinations

Tags: budget, airlines, flight-search-engines

Are there any airline pricing websites which displays prices to 5 airports from a departure location in just one search? I know I could try getting the pricing as 5 different searches, but would like to know whether there exists such a website or an option on the popular sites like Kayak.com?

The rationale behind this is to know the lowest cost to fly to any of these airports to get to the final destination. I searched through the questions, but am not able to find one that answers this query.

Comment: Did you try it with Kayak?

Comment: Many pricing sites will include nearby airports; Orbitz, for example, will search within an 80mi/129km radius, and Kayak defines "nearby" even more broadly, suggesting MDT (Harrisburg, Penn.) as an alternative for DCA (Washington, D.C.), about 129mi/208km away.

Comment: @choster I would like to specify the airports which it searches for. These might not fit the proximity clause that these sites use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for cheap flights without any preconceived ideas, you can try the solutions listed in [Cheapest flight to anywhere at any given time](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27100/cheapest-flight-to-anywhere-at-any-given-time) or [Travel site that found the lowest-price tickets from your current location](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23692/travel-site-that-found-the-lowest-price-tickets-from-your-current-location)

If you are looking for flights to several airports in the same area, many sites will let you include “nearby airports” in your search by checking a checkbox, including for example Skyscanner, Kayak, or ITA Matrix. See [How can I do a "broad" search for flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights) ITA Matrix even lets you specify a distance threshold and pick which nearby airports you want to include from a list. For an example, see [Which is the cheapest way to get to Vietnam from Europe in summer?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11615/which-is-the-cheapest-way-to-get-to-vietnam-from-europe-in-summer)

Now, if you want to search an arbitrary list of airports and then choose between them by price (say want to go to either San Francisco or Tokyo), it's also possible on [ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) and [Kayak](http://www.kayak.com/) and maybe some other sites as well. It's not particularly user-friendly (or advertised at all, really) but it does work: Simply enter several airport three-letter codes separated by commas and set the other search options as usual (I am not sure how many you can put, three definitely works).

Note that broad searches are never guaranteed to find the absolute cheapest result because pricing all potential fare combinations is much more difficult than simply finding a route. Unfortunately, that's a common issue with flight search engines, see the discussions in [What's a better way to find flights when cost is important and schedule is not?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39293/whats-a-better-way-to-find-flights-when-cost-is-important-and-schedule-is-not) or [Is there a flight search engine that combines flights from different airlines?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26780/is-there-a-flight-search-engine-that-combines-flights-from-different-airlines) or [this presentation by Carl de Marcken from ITA [PDF]](http://www.demarcken.org/carl/papers/ITA-software-travel-complexity/ITA-software-travel-complexity.pdf).

This also means that broadening the search could actually produce poorer results. Obviously, the cheapest flights from narrower searches should still show up and removing constraints logically cannot exclude them but the search space quickly becomes too big for current search engines to handle.

Comment: I tried putting CSV airport codes on Kayak and it gives random results, not really the lowest cost that I'm finding when I do a one to one search.

Comment: @edocetirwi On Kayak or ITA Matrix?

Comment: @edocetirwi Note that the more flexible you are, the more difficult it is to find the absolute cheapest price because the search space becomes too big, see the discussion in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39293/whats-a-better-way-to-find-flights-when-cost-is-important-and-schedule-is-not and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26780/is-there-a-flight-search-engine-that-combines-flights-from-different-airlines

Comment: @edocetirwi Coming to think of it, the fact that it does find flights shows that it also supports the same functionality so I am going to add Kayak to my answer. Beyond that, the results are not “random”, you're just running into the usual limitations of any flight search solution. Occasionally failing to find a lower fare that could be revealed through a narrower search is not surprising and ultimately unavoidable.

Comment: Random was a poor choice of word, "not ideal" is what I meant.

Comment: Is there no website, that would do 5 different search queries and merge the results when its displayed to the user?

Comment: @edocetirwi I don't know any.